# WCF method post json return bad request

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I'm here with a problem I can not solve.
I'm doing a post with ajax and json to pass data by WCF, but does not work ... gives me bad request.
I do not know what I'm doing wrong ...

My code is this

Service1.svc.cs:

```
namespace Teste
 {

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        string getdata = "hello";
        return string.Format("You entered" + getdata);
    }
    public string GetDataName(string Name)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered" + Name);
    }
}
}
```

IService1.cs:

```
namespace Teste
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetData", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetDataName", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetDataName(string Name);
 }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why when I do the post with the name, it gives me bad request?

greetings

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are creating two GET methods rather than POST.

Try removing `Method = "POST"`.